# CSS/HTML: Create ordered list with nested list that is all aligned left, but text must be squared

Tags: html, css

I have a list of headings, each of which has a nested list. These lists have a increment of numbers as the bullet points, and I want to make sure everything including the nested lists are aligned all the way to the left. I then want to make sure the text is aligned with the rest of the text, not so that when a new line is started it goes all the way to the left underneath the bullet points.

This is all much easier to follow with the examples below. This is what I have so far:
[image]

```css
/* Numbered lists like 1, 1.1, 2.2.1... */
ol {
 counter-reset: item;
 padding: 0; 
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 20px !ie7;
}

ul {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 list-style: none;
}

li:before {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 content: counters(item, ".") ".";
 
}
ol > li {
 counter-increment: item;
 
}
ol li:before {
 display: inline-block; 
 
 
 width: 50px;
}

ol ol > li:before {
 
}

ol li li:before {
 width: 70px;
}

ol li li li:before {
 width: 90px;
}

ol li li li li:before {
 width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>

      <ol class="heading">
    <li>TITLE ONE</li>
     <ol class="contents">
      <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</span></li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</li>
       <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur.</li>
       </ol>
     </ol>
    <li>TITLE TWO</li>
     <ol>
      <li>text 2 one</li>
      <li>text 2 two</li>
      <li>text 2 three</li>
      <li>text 2 four</li>
     </ol>
    <li>TITLE THREE</li>
     <ol>
      <li>text 3 one</li>
      <li>text 3 two</li>
      <li>text 3 three</li>
      <li>text 3 four</li>
      <li>text 3 five</li>
      <li>text 3 six</li>
     </ol>
   </ol>

 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the from point 1.1, the text when on a new line goes back to far, and I want to try set it in line with the start of the point.

Here is what I am aiming for:
[image]

This is proving difficult, and thank you to anyone in advance who comes back with some answer's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add `<span>`s to the other `<li>`s as well? If yes, this would be one way to go:

```css
/* Numbered lists like 1, 1.1, 2.2.1... */
/* Numbered lists like 1, 1.1, 2.2.1... */
ol {
 counter-reset: item;
 padding: 0; 
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 20px !ie7;
}

ul {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 list-style: none;
}

li span, li {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li:before {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 content: counters(item, ".") ".";
 float: left;
}
ol > li {
 counter-increment: item;
 
}
ol li:before {
    
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>

      
      <ol class="heading">
    <li>TITLE ONE
     <ol class="contents">
      <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris qu</span></li>
      <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse</span></li>
      <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a</span></li>
      <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit am</span>
       <ol>
        <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis auguesit amet enim uetur.</span></li>
       </ol>
                        </li>
     </ol>
                </li>
    <li>TITLE TWO
     <ol>
      <li>text 2 one</li>
      <li>text 2 two</li>
      <li>text 2 three</li>
      <li>text 2 four</li>
     </ol>
                </li>
    <li>TITLE THREE
     <ol>
      <li>text 3 one</li>
      <li>text 3 two</li>
      <li>text 3 three</li>
      <li>text 3 four</li>
      <li>text 3 five</li>
      <li>text 3 six</li>
     </ol>
                </li>
   </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can add spam to it indeed, however what do I do with the new span tag? what will this help me achieve?

Comment: You will be able to style the text of the li alone, see my result, isn't that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: AH I see thats fantastic! thank you, however did you take a look at the numbering? its still offer, I wanted it to increment by each sections. So title 2 shouldn't be 1.5 it should be 2.

Comment: Looking at your html I now notice it is invalid, I'm fixing it

Comment: For the future, I suggest you validate your HTML before posting on SO so you can be sure it's not a validation problem: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Okay my apologies, I didn't notice it was invalid. This is absolutely wonderful, I really appreciate this Jonas.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your html is invalid. The only valid immediate children of `ol` elements are:

> Zero or more li and [script-supporting](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0) elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element

Right now you have more `ol` elements as children of parent `ol` elements. They should be within your `li` items. See below:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <h1>TITLE ONE</h1>
    <ol class="contents">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis
        augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur
        sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur. Morbi in arcu nulla. Curabitur sed orci eget dolor mollis suscipit.</li>
      <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris quis augue sit amet enim ultrices consectetur.</li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>TITLE TWO</h1>
    <ol>
      <li>text 2 one</li>
      <li>text 2 two</li>
      <li>text 2 three</li>
      <li>text 2 four</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>TITLE THREE</h1>
    <ol>
      <li>text 3 one</li>
      <li>text 3 two</li>
      <li>text 3 three</li>
      <li>text 3 four</li>
      <li>text 3 five</li>
      <li>text 3 six</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Solution:**

Now styling is easier because you can target `li > h1` and `li > ol`

Comment: I would love to see your HTML, I am confused as I do have li elements

Comment: I see now thank you for correcting me, if I could ask you one more thing. Can you take a look at my CSS, and see how I would alter it to work with this?

Comment: I see another answer is fixing giving it to you.

Comment: Yes I have an answer, thank you ever so much for your input though, it was great.

Answer (score 0):

i have a way that works that works without the need to aadd all these spans:

http://jsfiddle.net/qGCUk/1083/

Forgive the ugliness of the css - I rushed it down :)

css:

```
OL { counter-reset: item; }
LI { display: block; }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
    counter-increment: item;
}
li{
    position:relative;
}
ol li ol li{
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
ol li ol li::before{
    content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
    counter-increment: item;
    position:absolute;
    left: -30px;
}
```

html:

```
 <ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
  <ol>
   <li>two.onesjidasjdioasjdiosajdiosa jdioasjdioasjdisaojdoiasjdoisajd oiasjdioasjdiojasidojs aiodjsaiodjsaoidjsaoidjosiadjoisajdiosajdoiasjdioasjdiosajdiosajdiosajiod</li>
   <li>two.two</li>
   <li>two.three</li>
  </ol>
     </li>
  <li>three 
  <ol>
   <li>three.one</li>
   <li>three.two</li>
    <ol>
     <li>three.two.one</li>
     <li>three.two.two</li>
    </ol>
   </ol>
     </li> 
  <li>four</li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: This is helpful however it misses out on the crucial part of it all aligning left, like Jonas's answer at the top.

Comment: As far as I understood your question the issue was that the 2nd line was below the Counter -> with my example that issue is fixed :=)